# Multiple "calculation AND assignment" operations in one line of python?

Tags: python, assignment-operator

Let's say I would like to divide by 2, add 1 and multiply by 5.

Something like

```py
x /= 2 += 1 *= 5
```

obviously doesn't work.

I tried different combinations using parentheses and the walrus operator, but couldn't produce produce something working, even less something well readable

Comment: Remove the latter two equals (or maybe all the assignments), there’s no point in assigning partial results to variables here, especially when it affects order of operations in a hard to read way

Comment: `x = ((x / 2) + 1) * 5`; if you really want multiple such operations, put them in different statements: `x /= 2; x += 1; x *= 5`

Comment: One could imagine a hypothetical application assignment operator `x ()= f` that would be equivalent to `x = f(x)`.

Comment: in the piece of code where I need it, it fits well with the general style, as there are many occurrences where an assigned variable gets manipulated using += or similar. So I thought something to chain them might be possible in places where I need several of them at once. However, the most readable and useful is probably doing it on several lines as suggested by the answer of @chepner or without "calculate AND assign" operators at all as in the first suggestion by LMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something you can chain. There's nothing wrong with the perfectly readable

```
x /= 2
x += 1
x *= 5
```

or

```
x = (x/2 + 1) * 5
```

Answer (score -2):

why r u adding those equal signs tho ??
something like this should do it :

```
x = 100

print((x/2 +1) * 5)
```

Comment: That doesn't change the value of x.